# Mapping table without clustered primary key

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

When I have two POCO classes in my `DataContext` (and I use them as `DbSet<>`), EF-code first creates a mapping table behind the curtain:

```
class Subscription
{
   ICollection<Product> Products {get;set}
}
```

and

```
class Product
{
   ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions {get;set}
}
```

and the secret mapping table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductSubscriptions](
  [Product_Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
  [Subscription_Id] [bigint] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

with a clustered primary key on the two ID fields.

**Question:**
Is it possible to create the table without the clustered primary key on both fields? Because I  have a many-to-many relationship here and therefor multiple entries like:

```
{ Product_Id = 1, Subscription_Id = 1 }
{ Product_Id = 1, Subscription_Id = 1 }
{ Product_Id = 1, Subscription_Id = 2 }
{ Product_Id = 1, Subscription_Id = 2 }
...
```

I removed the primary key, but a multiple calls to `DataContext.Products.Subscriptions.Add(1)` only add a single item, instead of the number of times it was called.

Comment: Why do you have duplicates in the ProductSubscriptions table? What do they mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to explicitly have an entity that explicitly does the mapping.  The relationship itself will have an ID as it's primary key rather than the composite key.  It's assuming (and I think rightfully so) that your intent is not to have multiple instances of the relationship.  Otherwise how would it know which one to edit or delete if you needed to do so?

Also, why *DO* you have multiple instances of the relationship?  Is one really different form another?  Or do you just need to add a "count" if a subscription has more than one of a single product?

It seems like you need something like this:

```
class Subscription
{
   ICollection<SubscriptionDetail> SubscriptionDetails {get;set}
}

class SubscriptionDetail
{
    Product Product {get; set;}
    int count {get; set;} // have a count vs. having multiple Product entries?
}
```